# JAX-WS WebService Client - "Response: '401: Unauthorized' for url"

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm trying to instantiate a Web Service Client in Java, which its url is secured by username and password. When instantiating it, throws a WebServiceException; here is the stacktrace:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '401: Unauthorized' for url: WSDLURL
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.WSDLContext.<init>(WSDLContext.java:68)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:207)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:49)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:18)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
at org.openuri.ServiceUtilityWS.<init>(ServiceUtilityWS.java:36)
at it.cartasi.pb.giustificatomotivo.util.Util.sendEmail(Util.java:110)
at it.cartasi.pb.giustificatomotivo.action.ConfermaAction.execute(ConfermaAction.java:36)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
at it.cartasi.pb.giustificatomotivo.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:68)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2140)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2046)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1398)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '401: Unauthorized' for url: WSDLURL
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:467)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:36)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1007)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:666)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.WSDLContext.<init>(WSDLContext.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:207)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:49)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:18)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    at org.openuri.ServiceUtilityWS.<init>(ServiceUtilityWS.java:36)
    at it.cartasi.pb.giustificatomotivo.util.Util.sendEmail(Util.java:110)
    at it.cartasi.pb.giustificatomotivo.action.ConfermaAction.execute(ConfermaAction.java:36)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at it.cartasi.pb.giustificatomotivo.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:68)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2046)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1398)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

Here my code snippet (I also set the Default Authenticator):

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            char[] charArray = password.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(charArray);
            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    user,
                    charArray);
        }
    });

    try {
        ws = new ServiceUtilityWS(new URL(wsdlUrl), new QName("ServiceUtilityWSSoap"));  // Exception thrown here
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    }
```

I can access it via browser using those credentials. Does anyone know why is this happening?

**Note:**

The application is deployed on Weblogic 10. If I run that code from main the exception is not thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a Weblogic 10 problem due to its URLStreamHandler.
I solved it by doing the following:

- Instantiated the WSDL Url like this:

  ```
  URLStreamHandler handler = new sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler(); //standard http handler
  URL url = null;
  try {
      url = new URL(null, wsdlUrl, handler); //forced this http handler here
      ws = ServiceUtilityWS.create(url, qName);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  }
  ```
- After solving that, I had a similar exception on the service operation call. To solve that, I added a custom Handler to the SOAP Message chain:

  ```
       Binding aBinding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
       List<Handler> handlerChain = aBinding.getHandlerChain();
       handlerChain.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {

         public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
           return new TreeSet<QName>();
         }

         public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
          final Boolean outInd = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

          if (outInd.booleanValue()) {
              try {

                  context.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, user);
                  context.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

              } catch (final Exception e) {
                  return false;
              }
          }

          return true;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following code was helpful (as example):

```
...
ClassImplementingPort port = service.getPort();
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "unsername");
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
...
```

This answer was taken from https://coderanch.com/t/430458/java/JAX-WS-Authentication-javax-xml

Answer (score -1):

This issue is also might be resolved with setting of parameter **UseSunHttpHandler**
Pass the **-DUseSunHttpHandler=true** into the weblogic start script

https://pravejay.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/weblogic-javax-xml-ws-webserviceexception-failed-to-access-the-wsdl-response-401-unauthorized/